# ROS Answers SE migration: learning_joy

Tags: joystick, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying the tutorial with turtlesim and joystick on ROS electric, and Ubuntu 11.4.  I keep getting [ERROR] [1324135517.676376697]: Client [/teleop] wants topic /joy to have datatype/md5sum [joy/Joy/e3ef016fcdf22397038b36036c66f7c8], but our version has [sensor_msgs/Joy/5a9ea5f83505693b71e785041e67a8bb]. Dropping connection.
I know that the call back has to be changed to sensor_msgs, but I am not sure how to do this.

Thank you,
Morpheus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12391/learning_joy/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Go to the teleop_base.cpp file and search for Joy::joy, it will in the joy_cb callback function, change it to sensor_msgs::joy.
Check if the

```
#include "sensor_msgs/Joy.h
```

is included in the file if not include it. rosmake the teleop_base and it should work.

Hope this helps, Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2011-12-20**:
Thanks karthik, I am new at ROS

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-19**:
if you don't know what is call back function then you have to go through the tutorials http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-19**:
Its just about the type of the object. In your teleop_base.cpp there will be a call back function in expecting a msg of the form Joy::joy you have to change that type to sensor_msgs::joy. Include the above mentioned header file also.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2011-12-19**:
I am new at this, and I am not sure what and where I need to make these changes.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-17**:
Thanks Eric :)

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-17**:
I've ticketed updating all the tutorials to use the new sensor_msgs::Joy message here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5306